# Running SSIS on SQL Server without SSIS installed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is a follow-up to this question:  [Running an SSIS package without the SSIS service installed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/running-an-ssis-package-without-the-ssis-service-installed)

I have build an SSIS package on my local machine but when deploying to a server, I get the following error:  "To run SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Services or higher."

Can an SSIS 2012 package in fact be run on a server that doesn't have SSIS installed?

Comment: I think that question you mentioned also answers your question. You need to have SQL Server binaries in order to run dtsexec.exe and only way to get those binaries is to install SQL Server instance. So I would say.. you can't run SSIS package without actual SQL Server instance present on that system.

Comment: Also, be aware of [licensing implications](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52903/licensing-standalone-instance-of-ssis)

Comment: Thanks JackLock.   This is being run on a SQL Server.  So I'm guessing that that would mean SQL Server binaries are installed?

Comment: You have to install SSIS binaries, which is a shared feature. You don't have to install a database engine instance.